# Laravel update associated table

Tags: php, laravel

User Model :

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function userInformation() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserInformation', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

User_Information Model :

```
class UserInformation extends Model {

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = "user_information";

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Here is update part :

```
public function updateUser($request, $id) {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        if (!empty($request->input('email'))) $user->email = $request->input('email');
        if (!empty($request->input('password'))) $user->password = $request->input('password');
        if (!empty($request->input('type')) || $request->input('type') === '0') $user->type = $request->input('type');
        if (!empty($request->input('package_size'))  || $request->input('package_size') === '0') $user->package_size = $request->input('package_size');
        if (!empty($request->input('package_expiration_date'))) $user->package_expiration_date = $request->input('package_expiration_date');
        if (!empty($request->input('is_deleted')) || $request->input('is_deleted')) $user->is_deleted = $request->input('is_deleted');

        if (!empty($request->input('title'))) $user->userInformation()->title = $request->input('title');
        if (!empty($request->input('first_name'))) $user->userInformation()->name = $request->input('first_name');

        $user->save();

        return $user;
    }
```

I can update users table columns in that function but i can not access and update any user_information column.

How can i update ?

users table's id = user_information table's user_id....

p.s. I dont know Eloquent working principles, i was working with Doctrine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your inputs have the same name as your database fields, you can use mass assignment. But be sure to set the `fillable` property in the model. Or you could extract only the required inputs and update. The below codes will only update when the inputs corresponding to the database fields are provided, if not they would be ignored.

```
//User
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'type', 'package_size', 'package_expiration_date', 'is_deleted'
];

//UserInformation
protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'first_name'
];

$user->update(array_filter($request->all()));

$user->userInformation()->update(array_filter($request->only(['title','first_name'])));

// OR

$user->update(array_filter($request->only([
    'email',
    'password',
    'type',
    'package_size',
    'package_expiration_date',
    'is_deleted',
])));

$user->userInformation()->update(array_filter($request->only([
    'title',
    'first_name',
])));
```

Comment: What if I want to patch? Is that work ? For my code, if i send to empty parameter, i won't update.

Comment: The above code is for updating/patching. It's the same as updating few fields or all fields. If you provide only `email` and `password` then only those fields will be updated. You can test the code and see for yourself.

Comment: Yes, if you send an empty input then those will be skipped from updating.

Comment: I used to use the method that you did in the beginning, it's too cumbersome. This does exactly that and is very short and simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
$userInformation = $user->userInformation;
$userInformation->title = $request->input('title');
```

Source : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Don't forget to save the user information like this

```
$user->userInformation()->save($userInformation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can populate `UserInformation` separately.

```
 $user = User::findOrFail($id);
 $user->email = $request->input('email');
 ...
 if($user->save())
 {
    $userInfo = App\UserInformation::where('user_id',$id);
    $userInfo->title = $request->input('title');
    $userInfo->name = $request->input('first_name');
    $userInfo->save();
 }
```

Or, you may use [associate()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) method to update belongsTo relationship.

```
$userInfo->user()->associate($user);
$userInfo->save();
```